# How to use discord4j in a spigot plugin

Tags: java, minecraft, discord4j

I am making a plugin for a friends minecraft server, they also have a discord server for this server. I am trying to add some integrations between the discord server and the plugin using discord4j. The plugin compiles fine, when I try to load the plugin, I get one of two exceptions:

1. The first time I load the plugin

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean io.netty.handler.ssl.SslProvider.isAlpnSupported(io.netty.handler.ssl.SslProvider)'
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientSecure.<clinit>(HttpClientSecure.java:79) ~[?:?]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.secure(HttpClient.java:1073) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.common.ReactorResources.lambda$static$0(ReactorResources.java:41) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.common.ReactorResources.<init>(ReactorResources.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.rest.RestClientBuilder.initReactorResources(RestClientBuilder.java:245) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.rest.RestClientBuilder.build(RestClientBuilder.java:226) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder.build(DiscordClientBuilder.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder.build(DiscordClientBuilder.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at nz.laspruca.tcplugin.util.Discord.<init>(Discord.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at nz.laspruca.tcplugin.Plugin.onEnable(Plugin.java:14) ~[?:?]
    at org.qrl.tcplugin.TCPlugin.onEnable(TCPlugin.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:494) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:408) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.loadWorld(MinecraftServer.java:435) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:216) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:808) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

2. When I reload the plugin

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.followRedirect(HttpClient.java:870) ~[?:?]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.followRedirect(HttpClient.java:806) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.common.ReactorResources.lambda$static$0(ReactorResources.java:41) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.common.ReactorResources.<init>(ReactorResources.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.rest.RestClientBuilder.initReactorResources(RestClientBuilder.java:245) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.rest.RestClientBuilder.build(RestClientBuilder.java:226) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder.build(DiscordClientBuilder.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at discord4j.core.DiscordClientBuilder.build(DiscordClientBuilder.java:73) ~[?:?]
    at nz.laspruca.tcplugin.util.Discord.<init>(Discord.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at nz.laspruca.tcplugin.Plugin.onEnable(Plugin.java:14) ~[?:?]
    at org.qrl.tcplugin.TCPlugin.onEnable(TCPlugin.java:18) ~[?:?]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:263) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:351) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:480) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:494) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:408) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:876) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:642) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:758) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:743) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:381) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:350) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:1007) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:846) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'httpClientConf' is already in use
    at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.createOrThrow(ConstantPool.java:113) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at io.netty.util.ConstantPool.newInstance(ConstantPool.java:95) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at io.netty.util.AttributeKey.newInstance(AttributeKey.java:55) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-55a78ff]
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConfiguration.<clinit>(HttpClientConfiguration.java:51) ~[?:?]
    ... 28 more
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.qrl</groupId>
    <artifactId>tcplugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>TCPlugin</name>

    <description>The offical TCPlugin</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <url>qrl.nz</url>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>module-info.class</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
        
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.3-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.discord4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>discord4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.DevLeoko</groupId>
            <artifactId>AdvancedBan</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

And the class responsable for the discord interactions

```java
package nz.laspruca.tcplugin.util;

import discord4j.core.DiscordClient;
import discord4j.core.GatewayDiscordClient;
import discord4j.core.object.entity.Member;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.qrl.tcplugin.TCPlugin.*;

public class Discord {
    public GatewayDiscordClient gateway;
    private boolean goBrr = true;

    public Discord(String token) {
        DiscordClient client = DiscordClient.builder(token).build();
        gateway = client.login().block();
        if (gateway == null) {
            logger.warning("Unable to connect to discord, oh well");
            goBrr = false;
        }
    }

    public void exitDiscord() {
        if (goBrr) {
            gateway.logout();
        }
    }

    public boolean logedIn() {
        return this.goBrr;
    }

    public List<String> getMembers() throws IllegalStateException {
        if (goBrr)
            return Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.requireNonNull(gateway
                    .getGuilds()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .block())
                    .get(0)
                    .getMembers()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .block())
                    .stream()
                    .map(Member::getDisplayName)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        else
            throw new IllegalStateException("No valid connection to discord");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have solved the issue by now, but it might come in handy for others.

It took me a while, but this works for me. It seems that there seems to be some kind of version conflict with netty that spigot uses. (a guess)

Mind the <relocations> tag.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>your.main.class</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/maven/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <relocations>
                            <relocation>
                                <pattern>io</pattern>
                                <shadedPattern>io.netty</shadedPattern>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>io.netty.*</include>
                                </includes>
                            </relocation>
                        </relocations>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```